# Showing a collection of sets is an algebra

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I am trying to show the above is an algebra.

For some reason the lecturer has wrote that the compliment of $(-\infty,b_0)$ is $[a_0,\infty)$. Why is this?

Also the complement of $\displaystyle \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}[a_i,b_i)$ is:

$\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^{n}(-\infty,a_i) \cup [b_i,\infty) $

Where is this in the above list?

Comment: The intersection of $(-\infty, a_1)$ and $(-\infty, a_2)$ is just $(-\infty, \min(a_1, a_2))$, so we can reduce a finite intersection of such sets to one such set. The complement of $(-\infty,a)$ is $[a, +\infty)$ for that same $a$. But $a_0, b_0$ are both free variables, so all complements of sets of the first form are indeed of the second form.

Comment: I see that many of your questions which received seemingly satisfactory answers, have none that are accepted. How is that?

Comment: I will accept them in bulk in due course

Comment: Sorry but I find difficult to believe that this is your plan since the chronological list of your questions shows questions with unaccepted answers interspersed with questions with accepted answers, with no rationale I can fathom. (Unrelated: Please use @.)